# ParseException while building with JDK8

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-8

I have an android application, in that there is a module which has a build.gradle file as below
`apply plugin: 'java'`

Complete application builds fine with JDK7. However when I build this application against JDK8 am getting below exception in the Java Module during the build.

> Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic
>   (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic
>   (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> ...while parsing com/java/Module.class

When I change the plugin to below`apply plugin: 'com.android.library` it builds fine even with JDK8.

Is there any know issue with Java plugin in android builds while building with JDK8?

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild` at first

Comment: Tried Clean Build many times before asking the question but its still the same exception when I build again

Comment: The cause for the exception in the link you have mentioned was 'Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define..' . However mine is 'Cause: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)'

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: As mentioned in the Question 
'apply plugin: 'java'' is the only line I have in my build.gradle file, which was building successfully with JDK7

Comment: if JDK8 is required only then use it to compile. Otherwise, you must be using JDK7 for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this line in build.gradle file and it build successfully with JDK8

`sourceCompatibility = 1.7`